# How to fill an integer array with underscore in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing a task on the leetcode.com
[Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/727/)

Given an integer array (for example [1,2,3,3,4,4,5]) and the output has to be like [1,2,3,4,5,*,*], instead of duplicates, I have to fill an array with _

My question is how to fill an array with '_' underscore?
Below is my code.

```
 public static int removeDuplicates(int[] nums){

        int l = nums.length;
        if(l==0){return 0;}
        int k =l;

        for(int i = 0;i<l;i++){
            if(nums[i]!='_'){
                for(int j =i+1;j<l;j++){
                    if(nums[i]==nums[j])
                    { nums[j]='_';
                    k=k-1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        Arrays.sort(nums);
        return k;
    }
```

> input ->> {-100,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,4,4}

> output ->> 5, nums[-100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95] <- instead of 95 it should be _

Comment: 95 is the value of `_`.
You have an array of integers, not chars.
Obviously, `int` is not `char`

Comment: The task page is behind login, but you can either a) return an array of strings, and then place actual underscores inside, but then the return value would not be an `int`, or b) based on the method signature, you may not be actually expected to place underscores anywhere. In that case, I would suggest using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as the placeholder, as they always get sorted at the end of an `int[]`. And if c) `_` is really expected, but the signature is correct, *after* the sorting step you can fill up the end of the array with them (`for(int i=k+1;i<l;i++)nums[i]='_';`)

Answer (score 1):

95 is the ascii-code of the underscore.

That said - you can not expect a character in an integer-array.
This leads to two possible solutions:

1. Maybe 95 is sufficent because it is the underscore. But I don't think so.
2. You switch to a String-array where the underscore can be representet. Don't know if that is allowed in your example.

Nevertheless if you stumble upon the number 95 you have a problem because it is difficult to know if it is the underscore or the number.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can't add `'_'` to an int array. It will be interpreted as the character `'_'` and converted to an int. In effect the conversion of `'_'` to an int gives you 95, that is the ascii code of `'_'`.

It will be better to use a special value instead of `'_'` as a special number to put at the end of your array, try with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you try to assign the value of `'_'` (which is 95 base 10 in ascii) to an `int`. You could turn your array into a String array, and parseInt and checks, but it's gonna be VERY SLOW. You could try this instead:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] ints = ...; //Read the numbers however you like...
        
        HashSet<Integer> hints = new HashSet<>(); //In a hashset, you may only add any number once
        
        
        System.out.print('{'); //Print '{'
        hints.add(ints[0]); //Add the first number to the hashset...
        System.out.print(ints[0]);
        for(int ind=1;ind<ints.length;ind++) {
            System.out.print(',');
            System.out.println(hints.add(ints[ind]) ? ints[ind] : '_'); //Prints the number, if it is the first time you encountered it, '_' otherwise.
        }
        System.out.println('}');
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your hints!
The assignment includes the following
Constraints:

1. 0 <= nums.length <= 3 * 104
2. -100 <= nums [i] <= 100
3. nums is sorted in non-decreasing order.

So I put 101 instead of _

/**

- Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once.
- The relative order of the elements should be kept the same
  */

import java.util.Arrays;

public class RemoveDuplicatesFromArray3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        int[] nums = {-100, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4,90};

        int k = removeDuplicates(nums);
        int[] expectedNums = new int[k];

        for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
            expectedNums[j]=nums[j];
        }

        assert k == expectedNums.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {

        assert nums[i] == expectedNums[i];
        }


        System.out.println(k + "," + " nums" + Arrays.toString(expectedNums));
    }

    public static int removeDuplicates ( int[] nums){

        int l = nums.length;
        if (l == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int k = l;

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != 101) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < l; j++) {
                    if (nums[i] == nums[j]) {
                        nums[j] = 101;
                        k = k - 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        Arrays.sort(nums);
        return k;
    }
}
```

//=>> output 6, nums[-100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 90]

// :) thanks!